# Weird (point) and (point-max) values in IELM

Tags: point, eval-expression

When I open [IELM](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InferiorEmacsLispMode) and type in `(point)` or `(point-max)` in the interpreter, it always returns `710 (#o1306, #x2c6, ?ˆ)` and `64292 (#o175444, #xfb24, ?ﬤ)` respectively. If I eval these functions via `eval-expression` instead, then I get correct values for the `*ielm*` buffer.

As `(buffer-size)` is just `(+1 (point-max))` (unless narrowing is in effect), typing it into IELM yields `64291 (#o175443, #xfb23, ?ﬣ)`, but evaluating it via `eval-expression` gives the correct buffer size.

While this doesn't create any problems, I'm just curious why typing these directly into IELM returns really weird results? Is there any technical/theoretical reason for that?

Comment: Typing into IELM changes the buffer size, I guess? (I'm confused how you can always get `710`, actually. I get a different number each time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IELM allows you to set another the current buffer, take a look at your Mode Line to see which buffer your IELM is running on, I guess you changed the current buffer. You can change it back with <kbd>C-c C-b</kbd> (`ielm-change-working-buffer`). To learn more info about IELM, type <kbd>C-h m</kbd> (`describe-mode`) as usual.